# how to popup a enquiry form when customer clicks add to cart button in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have installed a theme in prestashop. Now i want to remove the checkout section. I mean when a customer clicks on add to cart, a enquiry form should appear as a popup asking his basic details to submit. I dont want to display the price of products and disable online order functionality. I just want to show my products in website and when user clicks add to cart a form pops up.

Is there any specific module to do that or i will have to customize the existing module?

Answer (score 1):

Please use your prestashop in catalog mode. Then please change shop button in product.tpl, product-list.tpl to button activating your popup box email form, adding custom input field, including you product id, name, price and everything that is necessary. You can create your own module using $.post ajax or using add ons module